# Can I drive to Canada and re-enter USA under VWP?

Tags: visas, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, h1b-visas

I'm currently residing in the USA with a non-expired H-1B visa, but I stopped working 24 days ago, so I have 36 days left in my grace period. In about 36 days, can I ***drive*** to Canada and re-enter the USA under VWP to extend my allowable stay by 90 days? I just need a little more time to stay with my family until my wife graduates soon.

I'm a South Korean citizen (VWP country).

Comment: My understanding is that the U.S. doesn't consider visiting Canada or Mexico to stop your timer.  If that's the case, then it won't help you to do this.

Comment: @JimMackenzie that's only relevant to I-94 holders and OP is on a work visa.

Comment: @JonathanReez virtually all non-Canadian nonimmigrants have an I-94, including H-1B workers. But that doesn't prevent someone from going to Canada and reentering in a different status.

Comment: If you try to do that, there is a possibility that you would be denied entry in VWP status.  A less risky but more costly option is to apply for a change of nonimmigrant status, either to B-2 or to a derivative status based on your wife's. If you make the application during the grace period, you can stay while the application is decided. But questions about this belong on [Expatriates.SE].  What is your wife's status in the US?

Comment: My wife is under F-1. I was told by international student office that applying for change of status takes so long

Comment: My wife has F-1 visa. I was told by office of international affairs at Ohio State that applying for change of visa (H1B to F2) takes too long that it might not happen during the grace period. Would going back to South Korea and come back by air be less risky to get VWP?

Comment: @SejunPark: well, Change of Status taking a long time is *good* -- assuming the Change of Status was filed before the grace period ended, you can stay in the US as long as the application is pending, no matter how long that is, even if you go out of status

Comment: @user102008 and there is no negative consequence if the applicant leaves before the application is completed, correct?

Comment: Entering by air might help, but in theory your chances should be the same.  But a flight to Korea costs more than a change of status application, so it really doesn't make sense.

Comment: @phoog: correct